# parsing boolean value with Json

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm using json to send objects from Android application to Web Api application.
When i try to send an object which contains boolean value its value will be deserialized into false even if its true in json !
Here is an exemple :

```
public class myObject{
    public boolean value1;
    public String value2;
}
```

And I have this method to my object to the server :

```
public String PostObject(String url, Object obj) throws ParseException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create().toJson(obj));
    httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    String resp = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    return resp;
}
```

And finally here I'm sending my object to the server :

```
myObject obj = new myObject();
obj.value1 = true;
obj.value2 = "testing";
JSONHttpClient jsonHttpClient = new JSONHttpClient();
String response = jsonHttpClient.PostObject(myURL, obj);
```

And here my code from server side :

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public string test(myObject obj)
{
    //obj.value1 = false !!!
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the raw HTTP post value and see what's there - my guess would be the JSONHttpClient is not serializing the boolean value properly.

Comment: No, Here is the value of the json before sending it: {"value1":true,"value2":"testing"}

Comment: I've got nothing then - can you post the `myObject` class on the C# side? Maybe something weird about that class?